# Error connecting using JDBC Mysql

Tags: mysql, jdbc, google-apps-script

I'm not able to establish a connection to my MySQL server. 
This is the connection string:

```
jdbc:mysql://<my_IP_address>:1005/rs_pm
```

This is the line of code:

```
var conn = Jdbc.getConnection(connString, mysql_user, mysql_pass);
```

I've been able to write a native Java program using JDBC and it connects just fine using the same connection string/username/password. (Yes, I know the port is non-standard but that's how I have it configured and it works with the native Java app).

The weird thing is, I'm looking at my router logs and when I try to connect with a native Java app I can see the traffic coming in. But when I run the script in G Apps I don't see any packets being received by Google IP addresses.

Is it just me? Is there a problem somewhere?

Thanks in advance.

**Update** So it appears that if I use the standard mysql port (3306), the connection works fine. It seems as though something in Google Apps won't try an outbound connection on the port I had specified (1005), or any other ports I tried. Perhaps the jdbc connector they use only supports port 3306? I will file a bug since this behavior isn't documented anywhere.

Comment: Once you have enough reputation you should come back here and post your update as an answer so this question will have a complete circle.

Answer (score 1):

JDBC connection to a database server only supported to ports 1025 and higher.